# mini_cart_product_thumbnail not sizing to values set in etc/view.xml

Tags: magento2.4, product-images, mini-cart, magento2.4.5

I have my image sizes set in my app/design/frontend/My_Design/My_Theme/etc/view.xml but for some reason, the values for mini_cart_product_thumbnail are not being used in the minicart.

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            ...
            <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
                <width>76</width>
                <height>76</height>
            </image>
            ...
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

I have tried changing the type from *thumbnail* to *small_image* but it makes no difference.

Inspecting the output HTML, I see that the image sizes are being set to *auto*:

```
<img class="product-image-photo"
data-bind="attr: {src: src, alt: alt}, style: {width: 'auto', height: 'auto'}"
src="image_url" alt="Image Alt Text" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
```

The visual result is thus:

[image: Mini-Cart showing very small product image]

Other places using this same XML file are adjusting the sizes accordingly, any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config for Mini cart thumbnail image was changed recently since magento 2.4.0. So, if your magento version is >= 2.4.0, you have to double the size of  `width`, `height`, so your new code will be changed to:

```
<image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
    <width>152</width>
    <height>152</height>
</image>
```

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24743/files

Btw, you should inspecting the output HTML div `.product-image-container` instead of `product-image-photo`

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers!